# Indicator OnPageChangeListener does not work

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

I'm using the code below. But it works when you rotate the screen or re-run the app.

```
pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        indicator.setCurrentPage(position);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        indicator.setCurrentPage(position);
    }

    @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
    }
});
```

Comment: what are u trying to do

Comment: @Sandra set indicator to my viewPager

Answer (score 2):

I think you should write this to addOnPageChangeListener

> ```
> indicator.setCurrentPage(position);
> ```